# Pyspark split the file while writing with specific limit

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark2.4.4

I'm looking at specific limit ( 4GB ) size to be passed while writing the dataframe into csv in pyspark. I have already tried using `maxPartitionBytes`, but it is not working as expected.

Below is the one I have used and tested on a 90 GB table from hive- ORC formatted. At the export (write) level it's giving random file sizes other than 4 GB

Any suggestion here to split the files with limit size while writing. Here I don't want to use `repartition` or `coalesce` as the df is going through a lot of wide transformations.

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").option("maxPartitionBytes", 4*1024*1024(1024).save(outputpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) `spark.sql.files.maxPartitionBytes` is working on read, if you are doing some shuffles later final size of tasks and due to that final files on write may change

You may try to use `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` as according to the documentation it is working on write

> `spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile` Maximum number of records to write out to a single file. If this value
> is zero or negative, there is no limit.

If it is not going to do the trick i think that other option is, as you mentioned, to repartition this dataset just before write